# Хранение дерева в реляционной БД

Tags: дерево, база-данных, mysql

Всем привет! Ребята, столкнулся с проблемой хранения дерева в БД... так, как с базами данных работал соооовсем мало, прошу вашей помощи! 
 Цель такова: имеются категории товаров, в каждой категории товаров есть подкатегории и т.д, например:

```
Обувь--- Мужская
         Женская
         Детская
           |
           |----- Летняя/Зимняя               
                   |
                   |---- Кожаная/не кожаная/совсем не кожаная
                          |
                          |--Китайская/не китайская/японская
```

и т.д. Т.е кол-во уровней в каждой ветке не известна( может 10, а может 100)

Пожалуйста, помогите спроектировать БД для хранения такого вида деревьев

Заранее очень благодарен!

Comment: Ребята, извините, что-то у меня плохо отрисовалось тут дерево из символов =) Сдвинулось всё... Думаю вы поймете... если нет- могу скинуть картинку от руки нарисованную =)

Comment: Какая СУБД?
ну а если в общих чертах то структура примерно такая:

     ID  Номер записи
     parent_ID Номер родителя
     Name Имя

Comment: База MySQL =)

Comment: если у вас возник такой вопрос - рекурсия и хранить данные как предложил `SoftR`, вообще есть лучшее решение - `NestedSets`...

Answer (score 4):

Ну если следовать структуре предложенной мной то выглядит будет так:

```
 Id       Parent_id      Name
 1         0             Обувь
 2         1             Мужская
 3         1             Женская
 4         1             Детская
 5         4             Летняя/Зимняя 
 6         5             Кожаная/не кожаная/совсем не кожаная
 7         6             Китайская/не китайская/японская
```

Comment: А я бы еще и текстовое поле утащил в отдельную таблицу с индексами, а в эту вместо поля `name` поместил бы поле `nameId`.
Ибо, обувь "Мужская", да и "Женская" тоже может быть "Летней/Зимней" и придется дублировать каждый раз текстовое поле вместо числового.

Comment: Ну показан принцип , а не решение.
с кучей индексов ,человек просто запутается

Answer (score 3):

Классический пример, где "из коробки" хорошо работает модель представления [**Nested set**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). *Примеры и бенчмарки для разных СУБД можно найти, например, [**здесь.**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)*

---

Как альтернативный вариант *(в случае не слишком большого дерева категорий)* это дерево может быть сериализовано в `BLOB` и обрабатываться на клиентской части. Т.е, каждая запись типа *`Одежда`* хранит в себе некоторый `id`, который позволяет в любой момент восстановить все категории по десериализованному дереву.

*Таким образом, можно вынести код следующего типа на клиентскую часть*

```
SELECT Child.Node, Child.LEFT, Child.RIGHT
FROM Tree AS Child, Tree AS Parent
WHERE
        Child.Depth = Parent.Depth + 1
        AND Child.LEFT > Parent.LEFT
        AND Child.RIGHT < Parent.RIGHT
        AND Parent.LEFT = 1  -- Given Parent Node Left Index
```

Answer (score 3):

Методов много, выбирайте на вкус:

- [Проектирование баз данных: иерархические структуры. Деревья в SQL](http://www.arbinada.com/main/node/25.)
- [Способы хранения деревьев в базах данных](http://phpclub.ru/faq/Tree?v=w5u)

Все зависит от предполагаемых свойств дерева и его использования.

Answer (score 2):

Nested set одна из наиболее удобных моделей представления данных, если нужно использовать вложенные списки, создание каталогов.

Она понятна, главное прочитать небольшой мануал как там всё сделано и как работает, остальное дело за малым - попробовать, сделать и начать пользоваться.

В своём движке использую именно такое представление данных. Это удобно, экономит время выборки данных, можно легко выбирать отдельные ветки и т.д.