# Организация хранения категорий/подкатегорий в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server, kohana, проектирование

Есть страничка, на которой выводятся категории (рис. См.ниже).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует вопрос:
Есть ли более простой способ, хранения категорий, чем тот, который я придумал (см. ниже)? 
Есть таблица, в которой хранятся эти категории.

```
ID        Name            Position       Link
1         Авто            01-00-00
2         Грузовые        01-01-00
3         Маз             01-01-01
4         Камаз           01-01-02
5         Легковые        01-02-00
6         Газ             01-02-01
7         Заз             01-02-02
8         Книги           02-00-00
9         Зарубежные      02-01-00
10      К.Дойл            02-01-01
11      М.Твен            02-01-02
```

И.т.д.
Т.е. **первые** 2 цифры – это номер осноновных категорий, **вторые** две и **третьи** две – это номер подкатегорий.
Это все с учетом того, что потом в html мне придется этот массив распределять…, т.е. делая по нему цикл, я к каждому из этих категорий, буду применять определенные html-тэги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из вариантов - древовидная структура объектов.

Но если у вас предполагается хранение только трёх уровней вложенности(категории, подкатегории, объекты). То ваше решение имеет право на существование.
Единственное что, нужно разбить столбец position на три разных столбца.

Ещё попробуйте проанализировать, не подойдёт ли вам две связи один ко многим(с точки зрения архитектуры это выглядит более естественно с вашей предметной областью), что-то вроде такого:

```
Category (id, name)
SubCategory (id, categoryId, name)
Objects (id, subCategoryId, name)
```

Возможно с некоторой вспомогательной информацией, структура которой может отличаться в разных таблицах.

Answer (score 6):

Вместо того чтобы формировать и потом парсить такой серийный номер, лучше вынесите связи в отдельную таблицу (например [так](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/)) или создайте у дочерних записей ссылку на "родителя" (тогда у корневых элементов она будет `null`).

Для определения уровня вложенности нужно ещё добавить в таблицу столбец `level`. В вашем примере это будет выглядеть так:

```
ID  ParentId  level     Name            Link
1   null      1         Авто            
2   1         2         Грузовые        
3   2         3         Маз             
4   2         3         Камаз         
5   1         2         Легковые    
6   5         3         Газ         
7   5         3         Заз         
8   null      1         Книги        
9   8         2         Зарубежные  
10  9         3         К.Дойл       
11  9         3         М.Твен
```

Некоторые примеры реализации можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45442/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%94).

P.S. В принципе, речь идёт о тривиальной задаче хранения древовидной структуры в БД.

Comment: Лучше только думаю ссылка на родителя у дочерних элементов. Таблица связей - это всегда великая путаница, и то что приходится разгребать.

Comment: Я бы так и сделал, но не знаю какая-будет вложенность, а на каждую вложенность новую таблицу создавать....

Comment: @Konstantin78, приведённые примеры работаю при любом  количестве уровней вложенности без создания N-го числа дополнительных таблиц. В первом способе создаётся только одна таблица, которая хранит только информацию о связях, не более.